# Using GSON to parse an JSON object with an array of elements

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How can I use GSON to parse the following JSON object:

```
{
    "ProductsByCategory": [
     {.....},
     {.....},
     {.....},
     {.....},
]
}
```

The JSON object contains an array of elements. I am using GSON to try and parse the JSON and have the following POJO classes to assist me with this.

```
public class ProductItems {

    @SerializedName("ProductsByCategory")
    @Expose
    private List<ProductsByCategory> productsByCategory = null;

    public List<ProductsByCategory> getProductsByCategory() {
        return productsByCategory;
    }

    public void setProductsByCategory(List<ProductsByCategory> productsByCategory) {
        this.productsByCategory = productsByCategory;
    }

}

public class ProductsByCategory {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("permalink")
    @Expose
    private String permalink;
    @SerializedName("date_created")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreated;
    @SerializedName("date_created_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreatedGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_modified")
    @Expose
    private String dateModified;
    @SerializedName("date_modified_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateModifiedGmt;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("featured")
    @Expose
    private Boolean featured;
    @SerializedName("catalog_visibility")
    @Expose
    private String catalogVisibility;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("short_description")
    @Expose
    private String shortDescription;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("regular_price")
    @Expose
    private String regularPrice;
    @SerializedName("sale_price")
    @Expose
    private String salePrice;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFrom;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleTo;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleToGmt;
    @SerializedName("price_html")
    @Expose
    private String priceHtml;
    @SerializedName("on_sale")
    @Expose
    private Boolean onSale;
    @SerializedName("purchasable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean purchasable;
    @SerializedName("total_sales")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalSales;
    @SerializedName("virtual")
    @Expose
    private Boolean virtual;
    @SerializedName("downloadable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean downloadable;
    @SerializedName("downloads")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> downloads = null;
    @SerializedName("download_limit")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadLimit;
    @SerializedName("download_expiry")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadExpiry;
    @SerializedName("external_url")
    @Expose
    private String externalUrl;
    @SerializedName("button_text")
    @Expose
    private String buttonText;
    @SerializedName("tax_status")
    @Expose
    private String taxStatus;
    @SerializedName("tax_class")
    @Expose
    private String taxClass;
    @SerializedName("manage_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean manageStock;
    @SerializedName("stock_quantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer stockQuantity;
    @SerializedName("in_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean inStock;
    @SerializedName("backorders")
    @Expose
    private String backorders;
    @SerializedName("backorders_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordersAllowed;
    @SerializedName("backordered")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordered;
    @SerializedName("sold_individually")
    @Expose
    private Boolean soldIndividually;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    @Expose
    private String weight;
    @SerializedName("dimensions")
    @Expose
    private Dimensions dimensions;
    @SerializedName("shipping_required")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingRequired;
    @SerializedName("shipping_taxable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingTaxable;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class")
    @Expose
    private String shippingClass;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer shippingClassId;
    @SerializedName("reviews_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean reviewsAllowed;
    @SerializedName("average_rating")
    @Expose
    private String averageRating;
    @SerializedName("rating_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingCount;
    @SerializedName("related_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> relatedIds = null;
    @SerializedName("upsell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> upsellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("cross_sell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> crossSellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer parentId;
    @SerializedName("purchase_note")
    @Expose
    private String purchaseNote;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = null;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> images = null;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Attribute> attributes = null;
    @SerializedName("default_attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> defaultAttributes = null;
    @SerializedName("variations")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> variations = null;
    @SerializedName("grouped_products")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> groupedProducts = null;
    @SerializedName("menu_order")
    @Expose
    private Integer menuOrder;
    @SerializedName("meta_data")
    @Expose
    private List<MetaDatum> metaData = null;
    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    private Links links;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getPermalink() {
        return permalink;
    }

    public void setPermalink(String permalink) {
        this.permalink = permalink;
    }

    public String getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getDateCreatedGmt() {
        return dateCreatedGmt;
    }

    public void setDateCreatedGmt(String dateCreatedGmt) {
        this.dateCreatedGmt = dateCreatedGmt;
    }

    public String getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    public String getDateModifiedGmt() {
        return dateModifiedGmt;
    }

    public void setDateModifiedGmt(String dateModifiedGmt) {
        this.dateModifiedGmt = dateModifiedGmt;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Boolean getFeatured() {
        return featured;
    }

    public void setFeatured(Boolean featured) {
        this.featured = featured;
    }

    public String getCatalogVisibility() {
        return catalogVisibility;
    }

    public void setCatalogVisibility(String catalogVisibility) {
        this.catalogVisibility = catalogVisibility;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRegularPrice() {
        return regularPrice;
    }

    public void setRegularPrice(String regularPrice) {
        this.regularPrice = regularPrice;
    }

    public String getSalePrice() {
        return salePrice;
    }

    public void setSalePrice(String salePrice) {
        this.salePrice = salePrice;
    }

    public Object getDateOnSaleFrom() {
        return dateOnSaleFrom;
    }

    public void setDateOnSaleFrom(Object dateOnSaleFrom) {
        this.dateOnSaleFrom = dateOnSaleFrom;
    }

    public Object getDateOnSaleFromGmt() {
        return dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    }

    public void setDateOnSaleFromGmt(Object dateOnSaleFromGmt) {
        this.dateOnSaleFromGmt = dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    }

    public Object getDateOnSaleTo() {
        return dateOnSaleTo;
    }

    public void setDateOnSaleTo(Object dateOnSaleTo) {
        this.dateOnSaleTo = dateOnSaleTo;
    }

    public Object getDateOnSaleToGmt() {
        return dateOnSaleToGmt;
    }

    public void setDateOnSaleToGmt(Object dateOnSaleToGmt) {
        this.dateOnSaleToGmt = dateOnSaleToGmt;
    }

    public String getPriceHtml() {
        return priceHtml;
    }

    public void setPriceHtml(String priceHtml) {
        this.priceHtml = priceHtml;
    }

    public Boolean getOnSale() {
        return onSale;
    }

    public void setOnSale(Boolean onSale) {
        this.onSale = onSale;
    }

    public Boolean getPurchasable() {
        return purchasable;
    }

    public void setPurchasable(Boolean purchasable) {
        this.purchasable = purchasable;
    }

    public Integer getTotalSales() {
        return totalSales;
    }

    public void setTotalSales(Integer totalSales) {
        this.totalSales = totalSales;
    }

    public Boolean getVirtual() {
        return virtual;
    }

    public void setVirtual(Boolean virtual) {
        this.virtual = virtual;
    }

    public Boolean getDownloadable() {
        return downloadable;
    }

    public void setDownloadable(Boolean downloadable) {
        this.downloadable = downloadable;
    }

    public List<Object> getDownloads() {
        return downloads;
    }

    public void setDownloads(List<Object> downloads) {
        this.downloads = downloads;
    }

    public Integer getDownloadLimit() {
        return downloadLimit;
    }

    public void setDownloadLimit(Integer downloadLimit) {
        this.downloadLimit = downloadLimit;
    }

    public Integer getDownloadExpiry() {
        return downloadExpiry;
    }

    public void setDownloadExpiry(Integer downloadExpiry) {
        this.downloadExpiry = downloadExpiry;
    }

    public String getExternalUrl() {
        return externalUrl;
    }

    public void setExternalUrl(String externalUrl) {
        this.externalUrl = externalUrl;
    }

    public String getButtonText() {
        return buttonText;
    }

    public void setButtonText(String buttonText) {
        this.buttonText = buttonText;
    }

    public String getTaxStatus() {
        return taxStatus;
    }

    public void setTaxStatus(String taxStatus) {
        this.taxStatus = taxStatus;
    }

    public String getTaxClass() {
        return taxClass;
    }

    public void setTaxClass(String taxClass) {
        this.taxClass = taxClass;
    }

    public Boolean getManageStock() {
        return manageStock;
    }

    public void setManageStock(Boolean manageStock) {
        this.manageStock = manageStock;
    }

    public Integer getStockQuantity() {
        return stockQuantity;
    }

    public void setStockQuantity(Integer stockQuantity) {
        this.stockQuantity = stockQuantity;
    }

    public Boolean getInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(Boolean inStock) {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }

    public String getBackorders() {
        return backorders;
    }

    public void setBackorders(String backorders) {
        this.backorders = backorders;
    }

    public Boolean getBackordersAllowed() {
        return backordersAllowed;
    }

    public void setBackordersAllowed(Boolean backordersAllowed) {
        this.backordersAllowed = backordersAllowed;
    }

    public Boolean getBackordered() {
        return backordered;
    }

    public void setBackordered(Boolean backordered) {
        this.backordered = backordered;
    }

    public Boolean getSoldIndividually() {
        return soldIndividually;
    }

    public void setSoldIndividually(Boolean soldIndividually) {
        this.soldIndividually = soldIndividually;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Dimensions getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public void setDimensions(Dimensions dimensions) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public Boolean getShippingRequired() {
        return shippingRequired;
    }

    public void setShippingRequired(Boolean shippingRequired) {
        this.shippingRequired = shippingRequired;
    }

    public Boolean getShippingTaxable() {
        return shippingTaxable;
    }

    public void setShippingTaxable(Boolean shippingTaxable) {
        this.shippingTaxable = shippingTaxable;
    }

    public String getShippingClass() {
        return shippingClass;
    }

    public void setShippingClass(String shippingClass) {
        this.shippingClass = shippingClass;
    }

    public Integer getShippingClassId() {
        return shippingClassId;
    }

    public void setShippingClassId(Integer shippingClassId) {
        this.shippingClassId = shippingClassId;
    }

    public Boolean getReviewsAllowed() {
        return reviewsAllowed;
    }

    public void setReviewsAllowed(Boolean reviewsAllowed) {
        this.reviewsAllowed = reviewsAllowed;
    }

    public String getAverageRating() {
        return averageRating;
    }

    public void setAverageRating(String averageRating) {
        this.averageRating = averageRating;
    }

    public Integer getRatingCount() {
        return ratingCount;
    }

    public void setRatingCount(Integer ratingCount) {
        this.ratingCount = ratingCount;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRelatedIds() {
        return relatedIds;
    }

    public void setRelatedIds(List<Integer> relatedIds) {
        this.relatedIds = relatedIds;
    }

    public List<Object> getUpsellIds() {
        return upsellIds;
    }

    public void setUpsellIds(List<Object> upsellIds) {
        this.upsellIds = upsellIds;
    }

    public List<Object> getCrossSellIds() {
        return crossSellIds;
    }

    public void setCrossSellIds(List<Object> crossSellIds) {
        this.crossSellIds = crossSellIds;
    }

    public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getPurchaseNote() {
        return purchaseNote;
    }

    public void setPurchaseNote(String purchaseNote) {
        this.purchaseNote = purchaseNote;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public List<Object> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<Image> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public List<Object> getDefaultAttributes() {
        return defaultAttributes;
    }

    public void setDefaultAttributes(List<Object> defaultAttributes) {
        this.defaultAttributes = defaultAttributes;
    }

    public List<Integer> getVariations() {
        return variations;
    }

    public void setVariations(List<Integer> variations) {
        this.variations = variations;
    }

    public List<Object> getGroupedProducts() {
        return groupedProducts;
    }

    public void setGroupedProducts(List<Object> groupedProducts) {
        this.groupedProducts = groupedProducts;
    }

    public Integer getMenuOrder() {
        return menuOrder;
    }

    public void setMenuOrder(Integer menuOrder) {
        this.menuOrder = menuOrder;
    }

    public List<MetaDatum> getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }

    public void setMetaData(List<MetaDatum> metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    public Links getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Links links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

}
```

The code that I use is the following:

```
   public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
        {

            String mMessage = response.body().string();
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                try
                {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    final ProductItems categoryProducts = gson.fromJson(mMessage, ProductItems.class);


                    response.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Error", "Failed to upload");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However, I get the following error: GSON throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY.
I have tried to change the ProductItems class to taking an object for productbycategories but then I get the following error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2324 path $.ProductsByCategory[0].meta_data[0].value. I am now a bit confused.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to give a little more detail as to what is in this: "{.....},{.....}," or rather the structure of it

Comment: @Barns the entire json : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJoS5WetAfjMbjU-_YPbW0EPDJSmKpFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I noticed that in some of the JSON array elements like "attributes" has other array elements like "options" and these are probably being deserialized by the `Attribute` class... and so forth. Perhaps the problem is in one of these classes. This looks to be just a matter of going through each element and the relative class to see if everything matches up. Very Tedious!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the information provided in the question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @D.B. use the following link from the json response https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJoS5WetAfjMbjU-_YPbW0EPDJSmKpFk/view?usp=sharing and http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the pojos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is that the data is not consistent with the way the POJO is generated.

This is the specific part of the data that has the issue:

"meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 14232,
                    "key": "_vc_post_settings",
                    **"value": {
                        "vc_grid_id": []
                    }**
                },
                {
                    "id": 14273,
                    "key": "fb_product_description",
                    **"value": ""**
                },
                {
                    "id": 14274,
                    "key": "fb_visibility",
                    **"value": "1"**
                },

Notice how the "meta_data" field is an array of objects and that these objects contain a "value" field. The data type of the "value" varies- sometimes it's an object and other times it's a string.

One possible solution would be to change the `MetaDatum` class so that the `value` is an `Object`:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MetaDatum {

    ...

    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Object value;

    ...

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```